# SQL Procedure to Return Counts of All Unique IDs in Some Tables within a Schema

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure that grabs all of the tables in a schema that have a column called "ID" , once I have those tables I want to output the counts of unique IDs within each table.

ex.

table1

[image]

table2

[image]

Output:

[image]

I have the latter portion implemented but the first part I'm having difficulties with. Here's my script so far:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE get_id_counts
IS
    BEGIN
        FOR table_n in (SELECT * FROM dba_tables) LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM MySchema.' || table_n.table_name || ' GROUP BY ID';
        END LOOP;
    END;
/
execute get_id_counts;
```

Currently I receive the error : "%s: invalid identifier", I assume this is caused by the fact that not all of the tables in the schema have the column "ID"

Comment: Is this Oracle Database? Please Tag the appropriate DB. So do you need to find all the tables that has column ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your database is Oracle

Use the `dba_tab_columns` to get only those which has ID column

So extend your query from

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tables
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tables where table_name  in (select table_name from dba_tab_columns where column_name = 'ID');
```